# route planner view from kml file

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

I have a kml file generated dynamically that I can view in google earth no problem. It shows a route for a journey. Is there a way to make this more 'printer friendly' so that I can print this of for driving on a road?

Comment: The new mymaps will let you print friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your KML in to New MyMaps and you can print in friendly versions.

[image]

If you have your route loaded you will be able to print.
example

Comment: thanks - excellent! The link is: https://www.google.com/mymaps btw